# When I move an object, like a cube, other things, like a plane move with it

Tags: transforms

I'm making a bedroom in Blender. I added a cube for the keyboard (of the computer sitting on the desk of my bedroom). For some reason, the cube and the flooring of my bedroom moved together. I thought of deleting the object and added a new mesh but the same thing happened. Can someone please explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Most likely it is due to proportional editing turned on

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that they are separate objects - if the plane was created in edit mode, blender considers it to be in the same object as the cube.

If they are separate objects, make sure that your Proportional Editing is turned off. It's up at the top, next to snapping tools, shortcut 'O'. When proportional editing is turned on, nearby objects will move with the selected one.
[image: Proportional Editing]